# How to find a certain table in multiple word documents and extract it to a single excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I have a folder with about 300 single page word documents. Each document contains around 3 tables and also some text. In every document there is a table with table name "stackoverflow" for example.

Here is an image of my word document example:
[image]

I have a lot of documents like these, but all are different, except for the fact that they all have a table with "stackoverflow" in it (like in the picture).

What I want to do is extract all the names from these tables from all the documents to one single excel sheet.

What I tried so far is this piece of code:

```
Sub ImportWordTable()
    Dim wdDoc As Object
    Dim wdFileName As Variant
    Dim TableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
    Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
    Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel

    wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.docx),*.docx", , _
    "Browse for file containing table to be imported")

    If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)
        Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

        With wdDoc
            TableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
            If TableNo = 0 Then
                MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
                vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
            ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
                TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & "     tables." & vbCrLf & _
                "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
            End If
            With .tables(TableNo)
                'copy cell contents from Word table cells to Excel cells
                For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                    For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                        Cells(iRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                    Next iCol
                Next iRow
            End With
        End With
        Set wdDoc = Nothing
    End Sub
```

With this piece of code I can select which table I want to extract to excel, it works perfectly except for the fact that I have to enter the table number myself and that it only works for one document.

I also found this piece of code to select a table with a certain string inside it:

```
Sub Find_Text_in_table()
    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "donec"
        .Replacement.Text = ""
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindAsk
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
    End With

    Do While Selection.Find.Execute
        If Selection.Information(wdWithInTable) Then
            Stop
            'now you are in table with text you searched
            'be careful with changing Selection Object
            'do what you need here
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

But I'm not sure how to combine these 2.

Comment: @ShaiRado This is what I found/tried

Comment: Is the text `Table 2: StackOverflow` actually inside the table, or is it some sort of caption just above the table?

Comment: Its kinda tricky, in some tables I think its part of the table, in other tables its a caption above it. I did find out that either the table has a caption above it and 'name' and 'adres' inside it, else the 'table 2: Stackoverflow' is in the table and has no 'name' or 'adres' in the table.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I think I have your solution.
You will replace the following code

```
If TableNo = 0 Then
    MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
    vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
ElseIf TableNo > 1 Then
    TableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & TableNo & "     tables." & vbCrLf & _
    "Enter table number of table to import", "Import Word Table", "1")
End If
```

This this code instead

```
    Dim myRow As Row
    Dim myCell As Cell
    Dim TargetTable As Long

    For x = 1 To wdDoc.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count
        For Each myRow In wdDoc.ActiveDocument.Tables(x).Rows
            For Each myCell In myRow.Cells
                If InStr(1, myCell.Range.Text, "stackoverflow", vbTextCompare) > 0 And _
                    TargetTable <> 0 Then MsgBox "More than one table matches description" & _
                                        "Table #" & TargetTable & " and table #" & x
                If InStr(1, myCell.Range.Text, "stackoverflow", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then TargetTable = x
            Next
        Next
    Next x
    TableNo = TargetTable
```

What my code does is loop through each cell of each row of each table and record the table index if the searched text is found. It will warn you if more than one match is found but will use the last match found.

Comment: I get the following error: 'Object doesn't support this property or method' on this line: 'For x = 1 To wdDoc.ActiveDocument.Tables.Count'

Comment: Replace 

    wdDoc.ActiveDocument.Tables

with

    wdDoc.Tables

Comment: The script is working now but I found out that I think its impossible to search for 'stackoverflow' because sometimes it is in the table and sometimes not. Do you know if it is possible to search for "name" only? Because I tried but now it also finds tables with "businessname"

Comment: use "<name" with wildcards: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-and-replace-text-by-using-regular-expressions-Advanced-eeaa03b0-e9f3-4921-b1e8-85b0ad1c427f

Comment: @Chris If I use "<name" I get the following error: The requested member of the collection does not excist. Which I think means that it can't find it, eventhough I know for sure that "name" is in the table. Because when I search for "name" it tells me there are 2 tables containing "name" (the table with "name" and the table with "businessname")

Answer (score 0):

First problem, opening multiple files: you want Application.FileDialog(), as at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840210.aspx
I happened to use it in Publisher, but same applies here:

```
Sub InsertAndSizeWinners()

    Dim fd As FileDialog        ' File picker, to select images to insert.
    Dim nm As Variant           ' File name strings selected to insert.

    ' Create a FileDialog object as a File Picker dialog box.
    Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)

    fd.Title = "Select documents"

    If fd.Show = -1 Then        ' 0 = Cancel, -1 = OK, got list.
        For Each nm In fd.SelectedItems  ' List of fully qualified file names.
            ProcessFilename nm  ' Process each c:\dir\path\file_name.jpg.
        Next nm
        MsgBox "All done. You can start arranging now."
    End If
    ' Else, user hit Cancel on file selection dialog box. Simply end.

End Sub
```

This is a very simple loop that gets a list you specify, then calls a subroutine (ProcessFilename) to process each one separately.